# Inspiration resources for desktop UI design

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

For desktop application, does anyone has a good website showcasing best desktop application UI? Looking for some inspiration for my application.

There are a lot of website for Web application ... i can't find any for desktop application.

Comment: This site may be another place to post question:  http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: This may help you: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120771/where-can-i-get-inspiration-for-a-good-user-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a site, a book, [Designing Interfaces](http://designinginterfaces.com/), but I constantly find what I'm looking for in it.  It has many good designs for smart client / thick client applications.

Edit, [there's also a blog that is quite good](http://designinginterfaces.com/blog/)

Answer (score 0):

With desktop applications there is little creativity either possible or expected.

Most interfaces are based on standard controls and the challenge is to simply structure them properly and logically. The user has to see something familiar and find things where he expects them to be.

Any attempt to introduce non-standard design causes confusion in most cases transforming into irritation. Software bundles shipped along with different hardware (drivers/utilities) are notoriously ugly.

It's only with web application where creativity unveils itself. You basically have an empty page where you can do whatever you want - no borders, no limits. With web sites people do expect to see something different on each next site they visit.

Interesting enough, if you look at the screenshots of the new Office 15 (to come with Windows 8) it seems to imitate web design - a white background with scarcely located elements and plenty of white space.